# Deploying java servlets: how to atomatically do the .class file copying and restarting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, deployment

I have a servlet in `.java` file that I edit. After each edit I need to build it, take a `.class` file from `/target/classes` directory (I use Idea Intellij) and copy it into `/WEB-INF/classes` directory. Then I call `catalina-stop.bat` and then `catalina-start.bat`. Is there any way to avoid doing it manually? What is the general practice regarding deploying java web apps?

Answer (score 0):

If you need hot code swapping, you can use JRebel. It will load currently generated class file into jvm for you without restart of container.